# Pass custom parameters into Typedscript-defined Knockout component loaded as AMD using requirejs

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, requirejs

I have built a dashboard component that loads other components using the knockout component binding. Using Typescript. Basically it works.

The components are registered as follows ...

```
ko.components.register('camera-widget', {
    viewModel: { require: 'Scripts/app/Widgets/CameraWidget/ViewModels/CameraWidgetViewModel' },
    template: { require: 'text!Scripts/App/Widgets/CameraWidget/Views/CameraWidget.html' }
});
```

... and instantiated cusing the component binding (where tagName = 'camera-widget' and parameters =  { /* some initial values to have the component load its data */  }) :

```
<div data-bind="component: tagName, params: parameters"></div>
```

In Typescript the CameraWidgetViewModel class is defined as follows:

```
import ko = require('knockout');
import PagerSettings = require('../Models/PagerSettings');
import PagerSettingsViewModel = require('./PagerSettingsViewModel');
import CameraViewModel = require('./CameraViewModel');

class CameraWidgetViewModel implements CameraWidget.ICameraWidgetViewModel {
    constructor (data: any) {
         if (data.someValue) {
             // BOOOOM! data is undefined
         }
    }
}
export = CameraWidgetViewModel;
```

Compiled into JS the CameraWidgetViewModel class is wrapped in an anonymous function:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'knockout', '../Models/PagerSettings', './PagerSettingsViewModel'], function (require, exports, ko, PagerSettings, PagerSettingsViewModel) {
    var CameraWidgetViewModel = (function () {
        function CameraWidgetViewModel(data) {
        }
    });
});
```

How can I manage the parameters from the component binding to be passed into that inner function call?

Comment: Shouldn't the component be initialized using `data-bind="component: { name: tagName, params: parameters }"` ?

Comment: That's correct. Ahem. Thanks. Would mark yours as answer if I could.

Comment: I'll write it down as an answer so other people can find it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In knockout's documentation on the component binding, you can find its required syntax:

> To supply parameters to the component, pass **an object** with the following properties:
>
> - *name* — the name of the component to inject. Again, this can be observable.
> - *params* — an object that will be passed on to the component. Typically this is a key-value object containing multiple parameters, and is typically received by the component’s viewmodel constructor.

Source: [Knockout Component Binding, subheading: API](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html), emphasis mine

The way you've instantiated your binding passes the parameters outside of the `component` binding. They should be in an object behind a `params` property. You'll have to use this markup:

```
data-bind="component: { name: tagName, params: parameters }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't exporting anything from your CameraWidgetViewModel file so nothing is actually being defined. But I also don't think you're supposed to be exporting a class because it [looks like](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html) knockout expects a function to be returned, not a constructor.

I would try adding this to the bottom of your file:

```
function getViewModel(...args) {
  return new CameraWidgetViewModel(...args);
}

export = getViewModel;
```

Comment: Sorry, that export got lost when posting the question. I am actually exporting the class. OP updated.